# Filtering dates and strings with one autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter a range of dates while ignoring blanks and cells containing "0000-00-00"

I can post the entire code if needed but here is the snippet that I am having trouble with.

```
Set ComboRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lcRow, lcColumn))
ComboRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    "<=" & Finish, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Array("0000-00-00", "=")
```

In my code lcRow and lcColumn just signify the last row and column. Finish is a date for example 6/30/16. My problem is that this is removing my data containing "0000-00-00". I have tried changing my operator to xlAnd and xlFilterValues but neither worked. Thanks for the help!

[image: Example data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
ComboRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= Array("0, " & Finish), _ 
    Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array("0000-00-00", "=")
```

The 0 in the first array signifies greater than or equal to.

Comment: This gives a "Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed"

Comment: @BerticusMaximus - try now. you may need to play with how you load the `Finish` variable and the strings. I can't test this again until the morning.

Comment: That gave another error. It's not pretty but I fixed my problem by just looping though everything and unhiding the rows. If nobody else posts anything by tomorrow ill check your answer as a solution.